# Automatically console.log the name and value of all variables in a script

Tags: javascript, automation

I often find one of the most repetitive tasks when writing JavaScript is the need to constantly check the value of variables, especially as a script grows more complex.

Is there a way to automatically log the variable values to the console via calling a function?

e.g.

```
var foo = 1,
    bar = true,
    yin = ['item 1', 'item 2'],
    yang = 'a string',
    tan = $(this);

function() {
    yang = 'another string';
}

foo += 1;

yin.push('item 3');

function logMyVariables();
```

would log:

```
foo: 2
bar: true
yin: item1, item2, item 3
yang: another string
tan: [object Object]
```

Comment: What do you mean "automatically"? Like ever x number of seconds it logs?

Comment: @Jerry, good point, I just updated the question

Comment: You could store all variables in an object in the outermost scope, or make it global, and simply log that object to the console when you need to see your variables, for example: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fLyahnma/).

Comment: Are the variables you want to log global?

Comment: @DavidThomas, I'm after something that can traverse the script and log every variable it finds sequentially. This includes Global and Local variables, as they are encountered in the script. I don't think manually declaring them in an object would work, as this relies on already knowing their value.

Comment: Local variables inside functions and closed scopes (files that have a self-calling function to  make variables local) cannot be logged since they aren't registered in an object as global variables are (this, which in most cases is window)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `debugger;`. This will pause your script and give you a snapshot at that point of many things, including all variables, local and global.

Try to run the snippet below with your dev tools opened, you'll see the result. This works in Chrome and Firefox at least.

```js
function init() {
  var foo = 1,
    bar = true,
    yin = ['item 1', 'item 2'],
    yang = 'a string',
    tan = this;

  (function(){
    yang = 'another string';
    
  }());

  foo += 1;

  yin.push('item 3');

  debugger;

}

init();
```